# How do I fire an AWS IOT rule on two different groups of IOT Buttons in the same account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I'm new to AWS IOT and have a use case where I have two groups of AWS IOT buttons that I would like to have a rule fired for.

I know that I can fire a rule for all buttons with the query statement:

```
    SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/#'
```

I know that I can fire a rule for one button with the query statment:

```
    SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/G030MD023024ABCD'
```

What I am looking to be able to do is fire a rule for the two different groups of buttons or possibly Thing Types.  Something possibly like this, but I'm not sure how to set this up.

```
    SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/groupA/#'   or    SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/groupB/#'
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your use-case, particularly, who is listening on those topics ?